# Determining density involving scaled beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose $Y \sim \mathrm{Beta}(2,1)$. If $X = \theta{Y}$ (for some $\theta > 0$) how do I determine the joint density $f(x, \theta)$?

Edit: the density for $Z$ is $2z$. Would it be correct to say, then, that $$f(x, \theta) = \frac{2}{\theta} x$$

Comment: I would have thought you need more information about $\theta$

Comment: The question I did before this involved finding the density $f(x, \theta)$ for $X \sim \mathrm{unif}[0, \theta]$, which was easily seen to be $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for $x \in [0,\theta]$ and $0$ for $x > \theta$. So I'm inclined to think not, but maybe I'm wrong since I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I may have been mistaken in my assumption that finding $f(x,\theta)$ meant finding the *joint* density. I've edited that out for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if the density of $Y$ is $f(y)$ on the range $[a,b]$

then the density of $X=\theta Y$ with $\theta \gt 0$ is $f_\theta(x)=\dfrac{1}{\theta}f\left(\dfrac{x}{\theta}\right)$ on the range $[\theta a, \theta b]$.

So in your example where  $Y \sim \mathrm{Beta}(2,1)$ having a density $f(y)=2y$ on the range $[0,1]$ and $X=\theta Y$, you will have $f_\theta(x)=\dfrac{2x}{\theta^2}$ on the range $[0, \theta]$.

Here $\theta$ is a [scale parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter).  I think $f_\theta(x)$ is more often written $f(x; \theta)$ than $f(x, \theta)$.